# How to get the return value from onpostexecute method in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android application. I need to get the value from onpostexecute method. i.e I need to do some tasks with the return value from onpostexecute method. How can I achieve that? Please help me in this regard.

My code:

```
boolean val= false;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LongOperation1 op = new LongOperation1();
            op.execute("");
//I want the value here again


}

private class LongOperation1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            loadFeed2();
            return "Executed";
        }
            @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            dialog1.dismiss();
            try {
                     dialog.dismiss();
//mystuff
                val = true;


        }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(Taketest.this, "Please wait...",
                    "Retrieving data ...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: call function inside postexecute(), pass the value as parameter to that function

Comment: hmm yes i used global variable....in onpostexecute method I changed the value to true. Now I want to use it in oncreate method. How can I get that value?

Comment: dont code anything inside oncreate, create separate function say "init" then call this function from postexecute

Comment: take a look to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask

Comment: @user1455252 pls upvote the answer in the link suggested by blackbelt. he deleted the answer posted which actually answered your question. instead of returning a boolean value in that case return whatever value you like.

Comment: @blackbelt why did you delete the answer it actually answered the question?

Comment: @Raghunandan I dont know If my behaviour fullfil the stackoverflow netiquette

Comment: @blackbeltHi thank you so much...I am able to get the value using your code

Comment: @blackbelt may be this will help http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113385/user-posting-exact-duplicate-answers-to-multiple-questions.

Comment: @Raghunandan still I am a bit uncertain about it. To me seems a bit boderline. As you point out it is a bit different from the original answer but still it remains the same answer :). May a mods could shed a bit of light :)

Answer (score 1):

u can try something like this, 
make the boolean val as global  then

```
   Public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LongOperation1 op = new LongOperation1();
    op.execute("");
    // here should not check val is true or not because it will run before ansynch complete
}

public void init()
{
 if(val)
      {

   Log.e("val is","true");
      }

 }

 ...........

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog1.dismiss();
        try {
                 dialog.dismiss();
     //mystuff
            val = true;

             init();


    }
```