# Get a return value from OnPostExecute android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, return, return-value

First of all i have to say, i have read this:

[How to get the return value from onpostexecute method in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248639/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-onpostexecute-method-in-android)

And that:

[How do I return a boolean from AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask?noredirect=1&lq=1)

With no help, maybe i didn't understand what they were saying.
Here is my porblem:
i just need to get back the String value which is in my OnPostExecute method.
not from doInBackground, i need it from my OnPostExecute.

My code:

```
 public void max(String build,String cls)
{

    BackgroundTask3 myTask = new BackgroundTask3();
    myTask.execute(build,cls);


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fcur is" + Fcur,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

and:

```
public class BackgroundTask3 extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

    String capacity_url;
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    String finalValue;
      json_capacity = result;
        finalValue=parseMax();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"finalValue is" + finalValue,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        capacity_url = "http://www.skedge.co.il/ANCurrentCapacity.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String cls,build;
        build= params[0];
        cls = params[1];

        try {
            URL url = new URL (capacity_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String data_string = URLEncoder.encode("Fclass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(cls,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("building","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(build,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("hour","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(hour,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data_string);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            //here is the new
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");
            }
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

All i want to do is:
assign the value which is in finalValue String inside the OnPostExecute,to the Fcur (public String) which is inside to max function.

Looks very simple but for some reason i can't get it done.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to get a callback from background thread is to use `interfaces` as a callback from `AsyncTask` for example:

create an interface that can be called in `onPostExecute()`

```
public interface ResponseCallback {

    void onRespond();
}
```

and before calling asynckTask define it like this:

```
   ResponseCallback callback = new ResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onRespond() {
              //code to be done after calling it from onPostExecute
            }
        };
```

and pass `callback` to the `constructor` of of the `asynckTask` and call it in `onPostExecute`

---

of course you can modify the signature of the `interface` to what ever you want.

Comment: I utilize this also because thinking as interface is the better way to implement responses to asyncTask callback.

Comment: @Yarden Rotem, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13815960/3332734