# Why is in main thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hello here is my code:

```
package pl.polskieszlaki.przewodnikjura;

public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {
public JSONParser() {

}

@Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... url) {
    return getJSONFromUrl(url[0]);
}

public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String inputUrl) {
    JSONArray jObj = null;
    String result = "";
    InputStream is = null;
    // Making HTTP request
    Log.d("ps","url: "+inputUrl);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(inputUrl);
        is=url.openStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.v("RESULT: ", result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {

        jObj = new JSONArray(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    //return jArray;
    return jObj;

}

}
```

I always get "Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" - why?
I have AsyncTask.

Here is my code in Activity:

```
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    Log.d("ps","1Pobieram url: "+url); 
    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

Comment: main thread is the ui thread. you get `NetworkOnMainThreadException` coz you are trying to do network related operation on the main ui thread which is not possible post honey comb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call `execute()` on the instance of JSONParser, instead of `getJSONFromUrl()` . The method `getJSONFromUrl` is synchronous:

Change

```
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

with

```
jParser.execute(url);
```

to retrieve the result, check my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask)

Comment: Thanks!But how to get result - json ?

Comment: you are welcome. I edited my answer . I added a link to one on my old answer. the OP wants to return a boolean, you can change in order to meet your needs

Comment: Is it a possible that I use async result in main action like: JSONArray json;?

Comment: Hoe can I use async result (JSONArray json) in main Activity?

Comment: change  public void myMethod(boolean result); with  public void myMethod(JSONArray json);

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
Log.d("ps","1Pobieram url: "+url); 
// getting JSON string from URL
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

Replace this code to

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser().execute(url);
```

In doInBackground store the result in global variable and use that one to update the UI