# How can I set the text for a textview from an AsyncTask activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

I have got a Fragment Activity that contains a textview and another class that extends AsyncTask. Now I would like to use the `onPostExecute(String result)` method to set the result text in my textview that is in my fragment activity.

How can I do that? I already created a custom constructor for the AsyncTask class that takes in a context object. How can I use that??

This is how I create a task object in my Fragment activity:

```
String query = "someText";
Task task = new Task(this.getActivity());
task.execute(query);
```

This is a snippet from my task class:

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Context context;

    public Task (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // ??? What comes here ???
    }
}
```

Comment: is your asynctask an inner class of your activity class. asynctask is not a activity

Comment: no, it is not an inner class. Is that a problem?

Comment: @user2426316 please tell, is super neccessary to be called here? if so, what does it do? (off topic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TextView txt = (TextView)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.watheveryouwant);
txt.setText("blabla");
```

But you should pass an Activity and not a Context, will be easier ;-)

Or

```
    public Task (Context context, TextView t) {
        this.context = context;
        this.t = t;
    }
   super.onPostExecute(result);
        t.setText("BlahBlah")
    }
```

Should do the trick

Comment: In this example you're setting the text on a non-ui-thread. This might lead to problems?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html : onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes.

Comment: the second solution with the constructor did the trick for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I picked the solution from

[How do I return a boolean from AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask)

```
new Task(getActivity()).execute(query);
```

In the Constructor of `AsyncTask`

```
TheInterface listener;
public Task(Context context)
{
  listener = (TheInterface) context; 
}
```

Interface

```
public interface TheInterface {

public void theMethod(String result); // your result type

 }
```

Then

In your doInbackground return the result.

In your onPostExecute

```
if (listener != null) 
{
  listener.theMethod(result); // result is the String
  // result returned in doInbackground 
  // result of doInbackground computation is a parameter to onPostExecute 
}
```

In your activity class or fragment implement the interface

```
public class ActivityName implements Task.TheInterface
```

Then

```
@Override
 public void theMethodString result) { 
    tv.setText(result); 
    // set the text to textview here with the result of background computation
    // remember to declare textview as a class member.
 }
```

Edit:

You are also missing @Override annotation for your `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to the AsynkTast the instance of the TextView as a parameter, and call setText in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

in your case, simply following will come here:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.xyz)).setText("abc");
```