# Android AsyncTask: what is difference between execute() and get()?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Should I write smth like that

```
return task.exec(session, state).get(json_timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Or I can do like this

```
task.exec(session, state, result);
return result;
```

A have already read all documentation that I found, but failed to find an answer. My bad...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use `get()`. It will block the ui thread until asynctask finishes execution which no longer makes it asynchronous.

Use execute and to invoke asynctask

```
new task().exec(session, state, result);
```

Also you can pass the params to the constructor of `asynctask` or to `doInbackground()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

`public final Result get ()`

```
Added in API level 3
Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.
```

You can make your asynctask an inner class of your activity class and update ui in `onPostExecute`.

If asynctask is in a different file then you can use interface.

[How do I return a boolean from AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask)

Answer (score 4):

[`AsyncTask#get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) will block the calling thread.

[`AsyncTask#execute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29) will run in a separate thread and deliver the `Result` in `onPostExecute(...)`.

I would recommend against using the `get()` method except in special cases like testing.  The whole purpose of the AsyncTask is to execute some long-running operation in `doInBackground()` then handle the result once it's finished.

One example of normal AsyncTask execution would look like:

```
Task task = new Task(){
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //handle your result here
    }
};
task.execute();
```