# Can't post response from AsyncTask to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, http-post

I'm new to Android application development. Please find my code for AsyncTask for connecting a URL when a user clicked on a button.

```
    package in.mosto.geeglobiab2bmobile;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;

    public class OnbuttonclickHttpPost extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            byte[] result = null;
            String str = "";
           // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://URL_HERE/login.php");

            try {
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", params[0]));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[1]));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    result = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
                    str = new String(result, "UTF-8");
                }
              } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }  
            return str;
        }

        /**
         * on getting result
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // something with data retrieved from server in doInBackground
            //Log.v("Response ", result);

            MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

            if(result.equals("NO_USER_ERROR")){
                main.showNewDialog("There is no user existed with the given details.");
            }else if(result.equals("FIELDS_ERR")){
                main.showNewDialog("Please enter username and password.");
            }else{
                main.startRecharge(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

See my MainActivity Methods:

```
    OnbuttonclickHttpPost t = new OnbuttonclickHttpPost();
    t.execute(mobile.getText().toString(),pass.getText().toString());

public void startRecharge(String param){
    Intent inte = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getBaseContext(), StartRecharge.class);
    startActivity(inte);
}

public void showNewDialog(String alert){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Please correct following error")
        .setMessage(alert)
        .setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .show();
}
```

Here i'm getting an error. I don't know whats wrong with my code. Can any one please help me ?

Comment: HttpClient, HttpPost (Apache) are bugged. Async task can be too. You should take a look at "Volley" definitly more stable, easy to use !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong. You should not create an instance of your activity class.

```
 MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
```

Activity is started by `startActivity`.

You can make your asynctask an inner class of your activity class and update ui in `onPostExecute`

Or use a interface

[How do I return a boolean from AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask)

Edit

```
   new OnbuttonclickHttpPost(ActivityName.this).execute(params);
```

In your asyctask

```
  TheInterface listener;
```

In the construcotr

```
  public OnbuttonclickHttpPost(Context context)
{

    listener = (TheInterface) context;
    c= context;

}
```

The interface

```
  public interface TheInterface {

    public void theMethod(String result);

     }
```

In onPostExecute

```
    if (listener != null) 
  {
      listener.theMethod(result);
      }
```

In your activity class implement the interface

```
     implements OnbuttonclickHttpPos.TheInterface
```

Implement the method

```
     @Override
     public void theMethod(STring result) {
   // update ui using result
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Finally i was discovered new things. If you can make your answer more briefly, it can be useful to others.

Comment: @RadhakrishnaRayidi which part should i elaborate?

Comment: No no it fine. If you can add more details that would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong way to do it. The best way is if you don't need that `AsyncTask` anywhere else then make it an inner class of your `Activity`. Then it will have access to member variables of your `Activity` and functions so it can update variables easily in your `onPostExecute()`.

If you want to keep it as a separate file then you can use an `interface` to listen for a callback.

[This answer has an interface example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

just change your onPostExecute()

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    parseResponse(result);      
}
```

and then you have

```
private void parseResponse(String result) {
    if(result.equals("NO_USER_ERROR")){
        showNewDialog("There is no user existed with the given details.");
    }else if(result.equals("FIELDS_ERR")){
        showNewDialog("Please enter username and password.");
    }else{
        startRecharge(result);
    }
}
```

This is not doing nothing

> MainActivity main = new MainActivity();