# how to print text message on backgroundtask

Tags: android

below is my complete code which work fine if i m not using   `public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{ }` class   is show text mesage on else statment but now i want to use progressbar untill server not load problem is if server return data then code work fine if server not return data else statement not work show toast message code is stop unexpectedly what should i do?

```
     public class SecondStep extends Activity {

ListView listMainMenu;
String SelectMenuAPI;
String SelectMenuAPI2;
String SearchSchoolurl;
String status;
String message;
ProgressBar prgLoading;
TextView txtAlert;

String param1;
String Menu_name;
String School_name;
secondscreenadapter mma;
TextView schoolname;

TextView textview1;
int IOConnect = 0;

static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
String URL, URL2, URL3, URL4;
String id;
String title;
String tmpString, finaldate, enddate;
String startdate;
String startdate2;
String val1, val2, val3, val4;
String mode;
String s2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondstep);
    prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
    txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);

    s2 = "search";
    mode = HomeMenu.mode;
    if (mode.equals(s2.toString())) {

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        School_name = bundle.getString("Serachvalue");
    } else {
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        School_name = bundle.getString("School_name");
    }

    ImageView options = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.options2);

    options.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(SecondStep.this,
                    LinkButtons.class);
            startActivity(iMenuList);
        }
    });

    ImageView btnback = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnback);

    ImageView logoimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bitmap);

    logoimage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

    textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    listMainMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainMenu2);

    mma = new secondscreenadapter(this);
    new getDataTask().execute();

    // listMainMenu.setAdapter(mma);

    textview1
            .setText("If your school is not available in the list,.");

    listMainMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent iMenuList = new Intent(SecondStep.this,MealGroups.class);

    iMenuList.putExtra("category_name",  Category_name.get(position));

            iMenuList.putExtra("id", val1);
            iMenuList.putExtra("title", val2);
            iMenuList.putExtra("startdate", val3);
            iMenuList.putExtra("enddate", val4);

            startActivity(iMenuList);

        }
    });

    btnback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    // parseJSONData();
}

void clearData() {
    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();

}

public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    getDataTask() {
        if (!prgLoading.isShown()) {
            prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(8);

            // count=1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        parseJSONData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        prgLoading.setVisibility(8);

        if ((Category_ID.size() > 0) || IOConnect == 0) {
            listMainMenu.setVisibility(0);
            listMainMenu.setAdapter(mma);
        } else {
            txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
        }
    }
}

public void parseJSONData() {

    mode = HomeMenu.mode;
    if (mode.equals(s2.toString())) {

        SelectMenuAPI = Utils.SearchSchool + School_name;

        clearData();
        URL = SelectMenuAPI;
        URL2 = URL.replace(" ", "%20");

    } else {

        SelectMenuAPI = Utils.Schoolname + School_name;
        clearData();
        URL = SelectMenuAPI;
        URL2 = URL.replace(" ", "%20");
    }

    SelectMenuAPI2 = Utils.getSchedule;

    clearData();
    URL3 = SelectMenuAPI2;
    URL4 = URL3.replace(" ", "%20");

    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams
                .setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(URL2);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            str += line;
        }

        HttpClient client2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client2.getParams(),
                15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client2.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request2 = new HttpGet(URL4);
        HttpResponse response2 = client2.execute(request2);
        InputStream atomInputStream2 = response2.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                atomInputStream2));

        String line2;
        String str2 = "";
        while ((line2 = in2.readLine()) != null) {
            str2 += line2;
        }

        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);

        status = json2.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {

            JSONArray school = json2.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < school.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = school.getJSONObject(i);

                Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object
                        .getString("school_id")));
                Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));

            }

        }

        else {

            mode = HomeMenu.mode;
            if (mode.equals(s2.toString())) {
                textview1
                        .setText("No school found,.");
            } else {
                textview1
                        .setText("No school found in "
                                + School_name
                                + ",.");
            }

        }

        JSONObject json3 = new JSONObject(str2);
        // message = json2.getString("message");
        status = json3.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {

            JSONArray school = json3.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int k = 0; k < school.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) school.getJSONObject(k);
                id = jb.getString("schedule_id");
                title = jb.getString("title");

                startdate = jb.getString("start_date");
                tmpString = startdate.replace(" 00:00:00", "");
                finaldate = tmpString.replace("-", "/");
                enddate = jb.getString("end_date");

            }

            val1 = id;
            val2 = title;
            val3 = finaldate;
            val4 = enddate;

        }

        else {

            JSONArray school1 = json3.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < school1.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = school1.getJSONObject(i);

                Category_ID.add((long) i);
                Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));

            }

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 }
```

**My Logcat is:**

```
        AndroidRuntime(574): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
   AndroidRuntime(574): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing  
  doInBackground()

 AndroidRuntime(574):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
  AndroidRuntime(574):  at   
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
  AndroidRuntime(574):  at 
  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
 AndroidRuntime(574):   at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
 AndroidRuntime(574): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 AndroidRuntime(574):at    
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
AndroidRuntime(574):    at   
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
    AndroidRuntime(574):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
 AndroidRuntime(574): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException:  
  Only     the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
  AndroidRuntime(574): at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2802)
 AndroidRuntime(574):at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:594)
 0AndroidRuntime(574):at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
  AndroidRuntime(574):at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
  AndroidRuntime(574):at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
   AndroidRuntime(574):at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
  AndroidRuntime(574):at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
  AndroidRuntime(574):at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
  0AndroidRuntime(574):at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5378)
 AndroidRuntime(574):at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2688)
 AndroidRuntime(574):at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
 AndroidRuntime(574):at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
 AndroidRuntime(574):at com.schoollunchapp.SecondStep.parseJSONData(SecondStep.java:281)
AndroidRuntime(574):at    
  com.schoollunchapp.SecondStep$getDataTask.doInBackground(SecondStep.java:177)
  AndroidRuntime(574):  at    
  com.schoollunchapp.SecondStep$getDataTask.doInBackground(SecondStep.java:1)
  AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    AndroidRuntime(574):    at     
  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Comment: inmethod parseJSONData();  else statement not show textview message code stop unexpectedly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to update `UI part in doInBackground()` of `AsyncTask` which is not allowed directly

Check Following inside  `parseJSONData()` which is called from `doInBackground()`

```
 if (mode.equals(s2.toString())) {
        textview1.setText("No school found,.");
    } else {
        textview1.setText("No school found in "+ School_name+ ",.");
    }
```

if you are to update the `UI part` do same in `onPostExecute()` of `AsyncTask`

Comment: so how do i show this messages in background therad with conditions? if mode.equals(S2.String);

Comment: @user2778836 do same in `onPostExecute() of AsyncTask`, would be much better than using anything else.

Comment: but how do i indicate from   onpostexecute  from inside parseJSONData() that now show this toast message?

Comment: `onPostExecute` is better  , change the return types in `Aynctask` and of the method parseJSONData and also `doinbackground` make it to return string and in `onPostExecute` check the condition with  result.

Comment: @Tarsem , I am not the one who did a down vote . I just expressed by concern

Answer (score 0):

You are updating ui from a background thread which is not possible.

```
textview1.setText("No school found");
```

You need to update ui on the ui thread. Do it in `onPostExecute`

Return result of the background computation in `doInbackground`. The result of `doInbackground` computation is a param to `onPostExecute`. So based on the result update ui in `onPostExecute`.

You can also use `runOnUiThread` which is a method of activity class.

If your asynctask is not an inner class of your activity you can use interface

[Can't post response from AsyncTask to MainActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723282/cant-post-response-from-asynctask-to-mainactivity/18723363#18723363)

Comment: but how do i check which message show there is two textview message which check first   mode = HomeMenu.mode;
    if (mode.equals(s2.toString())) {

Comment: return the mode in doinbackground check and update textview in onPostexcute

Comment: @user2778836 i suggest you read the docs has an example and details you need http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `runOnUiThead()` like below in your worker thread :

```
mode = HomeMenu.mode;

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        if (mode.equals(s2.toString())) 
        {
            textview1.setText("No school found,.");
        } 
        else 
        {
            textview1.setText("No school found in " + School_name + ",.");
        }           
    }
});
```

Comment: but checkmy code i apply condtions mode = HomeMenu.mode;
    if (mode.equals(s2.toString())) { show diffrent textview else show another textview

Comment: where i placerunOnUiThread(new Runnable() ? at the last of Activity??

Comment: u mean add conditions in runonUithread?? whrere i place this piece of code?

Comment: just only tell me where i place this all runonUitheard code? inside main clas or last of the application code?

Comment: and how do i identify code goes on else statement in parseJSONData(); method??

Comment: For that you have to debug your code I have answered your main question