# Sending/receiving an ArrayList to/from AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-asynctask

Using JSON I have trimmed the URL of an online gallery and filled an array list with the image sources, or image URLs.

I now want to return the ArrayList back to the MainActivity so that I can then convert the ArrayList to an Array and use that Array of Image URLs to download the images and put them in a gridview.

My problem is that I am not returning the ArrayList from the AsyncTask to the MainActivity. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new myAsyncTask().execute(list);

    Log.v("jknfsda: ",list.get(1));

    //TextView line1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.line1);
    //for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
      //  line1.append(i+1 + ": " + list.get(i));

 }
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
public class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

static String quellaGalleryInfo = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.quellabicycle.com%2Fgallery%22&format=json&callback=";
public  static ArrayList<String> urlArr = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... list) {

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(quellaGalleryInfo);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = null; // Hold all of the data from the URL

    try{

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); //Response from webservice (may or may not get)
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); // all the content from the requested URL along with headers etc.
        inputStream = entity.getContent(); // get maincontent from URL
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"),8);// Read all data from inputStream until buffer is full
        StringBuilder theStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();//Store all the data

        String line = null;

        while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
            theStringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        //read all the data from the buffer until nothing is left

        result = theStringBuilder.toString(); // everything now inside result

    }

    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally { //close inputstream
        try{
            if(inputStream !=null) inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject;

        try{

            Log.v("JSONParser Result: ", result);

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);//object of all the data
            JSONObject queryJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("query");//get query objects
            JSONObject resultsJSONObject = queryJSONObject.getJSONObject("results");//get results object inside of query object
            JSONObject bodyJSONObject = resultsJSONObject.getJSONObject("body");
            JSONArray divJSONArray = bodyJSONObject.getJSONArray("div");
            JSONObject div_position_zero = divJSONArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray ulJSONArray = div_position_zero.getJSONArray("ul");
            JSONObject ul_position_two = ulJSONArray.getJSONObject(2);
            JSONArray liJSONArray = ul_position_two.getJSONArray("li");

            for(int i=0; i < liJSONArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject li_position = liJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject a_JSONObject = li_position.getJSONObject("a");
                JSONObject imgJSONObject = a_JSONObject.getJSONObject("img");
                urlArr.add(imgJSONObject.getString("src"));//final object where data resides
            }

            for(String item : urlArr){

                Log.v("JSONParser list items: ", item);

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}


//protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String>... list){
  //  if(MainActivity.list.size()>0){
    //    MainActivity.list.clear();

    //for(int i =0; i<urlArr.size();i++){
      //  Log.v("ope urlarr: ", urlArr.get(i));

        //MainActivity.list.add(urlArr.get(i));
    //}
    }



}
```

}

It works up until here 
Log.v("JSONParser list items: ", item); 
and then my LogCat just goes blank.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, there are two mistakes:
The first is you are passing an instance of the list to the asynctask, but never filling it with result: instead you are creating and filling a new ArrayList called urlArr. You should fill the one retrieved in the doInBackground() parameters. Because of the varargs syntax, you can do it in this way:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = list[0];
```

This is because, in the vararg syntax, you can pass a variable number of arguments, and they will be represented as an array called, in your case, "list".

The second error is you cannot know when the asynctask execution will terminate. In the onCreate method you are going to read the result just after the call. But asynctask is basically a wrapper to a Java Thread, and is intended to execute code asyncronously. When you call

```
Log.v("jknfsda: ",list.get(1));
```

your array is probably still empty. You should use a callback to notify the activity the results are ready. A simple way to do it is to pass an activity instance to your asynctask class

```
new myAsyncTask(this).execute(list);
```

, retrieve it in the asynctask class and store it in a field

```
protected ArrayList<String> myAsyncTask(MainActivity context){...}
```

and, in the end, notify the activity in the onPostExecute calling a method in the activity. In example, if you created a method called myResultsAreReady() in the activity, you can call it as:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String>... list){
    context.myResultsAreReady();
}
```

Obviously you can use that method for sending data to the activity, if you wish ;)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I made the aforementioned changes. But..  MainActivity context; public myAsyncTask(MainActivity context) { this.context=context; } //would not let me make it void, says it wont get used// and.... protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String>... list){ context.myResultsAreReady(); } //onpostexecute is never used.// Am I correctly retrieving the activity instance?

Comment: I'm managing to get 'myList' to return to the myResultsAreReady() method in the MainActivity. But, the return statement still seems not to be working as I still get an outofbounds exception(for the onCreate log)? From here, I am planning to use the ArrayList of image URLs that I now have and set them to a gridview, what do you think is the best way to go about doing that? Should I just continue on from the myResultsAreReady() method and set an adapter from there? thanks again for your time

Comment: For the "void" matter, sorry, my error ;) The doInBackrgound() method should return a value: that value is fed as argument in the onPostExecute call. The default way to implement this is retrieving your images from doInBackground (executed in a background thread), then return it and take it in the onPostExecute (executed in the UI thread). I see your list is empty before the AsyncTask call, for the sake of cleaness you can initialize it directly in the doInBackground and return it calling context.myResultsAreReady(myList) in the onPostExecute. In the activity you'll get back your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the postexecute in the main activity as seen below.

```
  new myAsyncTask({
            @Override
            void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> Param){
                //Should be able to do something here
            }
        }).execute();
```

reference
[Returning an ArrayList in android AsyncTask class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446190/returning-an-arraylist-in-android-asynctask-class)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had actually come across this but I get the error "Annotations are not allowed here" for @override...?

Comment: I believe you still have to include the onpostexecute in you async task so that you can override it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AsyncTask`:

Return the correct value at the end of `doInBackground`, you are always returning `null`.

```
for(String item : urlArr){
   Log.v("JSONParser list items: ", item);
}
return urlArr;
```

And you will have access to it in the `onPostExecute`, just uncomment yours and use the list parameter (you can can use a non static `ArrayList` too).

Comment: Thanks for your response. My mistake - I did have it as return urlArr all along but for some reason changed it.