# get json data in ListView with AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I would like to display some data from my server in my `ListView` with an `asyncTask`. The connection and `JsonParser` work well, but I have an error in my `OnPostExecute()`, when I try to put my data in the `ListView`.

So, this is the class that calls the `asynctask`:

```
public class GetInfo extends Activity{ 

    ListView listeView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);    
        setContentView(R.layout.listdata);   
        listeView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.maListeView);     

        GetJson getJson = new GetJson(GetInfo.this);
        getJson.execute();           
    }
}
```

Here there are no problems. This is my class `AsyncTask`:

```
class GetJson extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer,  ArrayList<String>> {

    private Context Mycontext;
    private ListView listview; 
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ArrayList<String> donnees;
    private ListActivity listAct;

    public GetJson(GetInfo getInfo) {
        Mycontext = getInfo;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        this.pDialog  = new ProgressDialog(Mycontext);
        this.pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        this.pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        this.pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.pDialog.show();    
    }

    @Override
    protected  ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {          
        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        JSONObject json_data=null;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        this.donnees = new ArrayList<String>();

        try{
            //commmand http
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.100/timesync.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("taghttppost",""+e.toString());           
        }

        //parse response
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));         
            StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();           
            String line = null;            
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();

            result = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("tagconvertstr",""+e.toString());
        }        

        //get json data
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);             
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {             
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                this.donnees.add("date :"+ json_data.getString("time") + " ou " +
                    json_data.getString("date") + json_data.getString("hour"));     
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            Log.i("tagjsonexp",""+e.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.i("tagjsonpars",""+e.toString());
        }
        return this.donnees;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> donnees) {    
        super.onPostExecute(donnees);

        this.pDialog.dismiss();

        for(int i=0;i<donnees.size();i++)
        {             
            Log.i("time", donnees.get(i));
        } 

        // this.arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Mycontext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, this.donnees);
        // this.listview.setAdapter(this.arrayadapter);
    }
}
```

My problem is the commented lines:

```
// this.arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Mycontext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, this.donnees);
// this.listview.setAdapter(this.arrayadapter);
```

and I don't understand why ...

This is my error:

```
11-05 16:43:36.560: E/AndroidRuntime(11200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 16:43:36.560: E/AndroidRuntime(11200): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 16:43:36.560: E/AndroidRuntime(11200):at com.json.GetJson.onPostExecute(Adapter.java:134)
11-05 16:43:36.560: E/AndroidRuntime(11200):at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
11-05 16:43:36.560: E/AndroidRuntime(11200):at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-05 16:43:36.560: E/AndroidRuntime(11200):at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)

.
.
.
```

The result is being logged, so I'm pretty sure that my code is passed into `OnPostExecute()`.

Comment: have you already declared the listview?

Comment: there are many response in same time=) so i try your solution , because it's true that there isn't listView in my constructor in GetJson

Comment: THANK YOU Amulya ! it's work ! i'am very stupid to forget to put my listview in the constructor ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your list view is not initialized.

Step 1) Update the `AsyncTask` constructor:

```
public GetJson(GetInfo getInfo, ListView list) {
    Mycontext = getInfo;
    listView = list;
}
```

Step 2) Do this in `OnCreate`

```
GetJson getJson = new GetJson(GetInfo.this, listeView);
getJson.execute();
```

Comment: Everything work putting in my constructor my ListView from getInfo .
Thank to your response everybody =)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `private ListView listview;` line from the `GetJson` class.
The problem is you are accessing the `listview` object of `GetJson` class(which is'nt initialized) instead of the `Activity's` `listview` object.

Access the listview of `GetInfo Activity` directly like this

```
listview.setAdapter(this.arrayadapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListView listview` is not initialized in`GetJSON`. Hence you get `NullPointerException`.

You probably want to make asynctask an inner class of your activity and remove the declaration of `listview` in `GetJSON` since if you make it inner class it is already declared as a class member in `GetInfo`.

`listeView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.maListeView)` is in `GetInfo`.

Or use a interface as callback and set the listview in your activity class for example

[How do I return a boolean from AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask)

Instead of boolean in the example its `ArrayList<String> donnees` in your case.

Comment: that good, i put my listView in my constructor in asyncTaks and it's work =) ( show Amulya comments)

Comment: @ThomasTrabelsi i prefer the delegate pattern as suggested by blackbelt in the the link provided in my post. left to you to decide

Comment: @ThomasTrabelsi may this help you decide http://www.vogella.com/articles/DesignPatterns/article.html

Comment: Thank i going to see your link, It may be beneficial ;)

Answer (score 0):

Which ListView are you trying to use? One in GetInfo class or one in GetJson class?

The one you have declared in GetJson class need to be instantiated if you want to use it as

```
listeView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.xxxx);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling any UI operations on PostExecute Menthod then try under this :

```
Handler refresh = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        refresh.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run( ){
                             // try UI here .
                            });
```