# Receiving response from HTTP request

Tags: java, php, android, httpclient, httpresponse

I am new to Java and I am trying to figure out how to receive a response from an HTTP request to a PHP page.

here is my main HTTP code:

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..
    }
}
```

and this is what I am using to send the request:

```
new RequestTask().execute("http://www.mywebsite.com/registercheck.php?first=" + first2 + "&last=" + last2 + "&dispname=" + display2 + "&email=" + email2 + "&password=" + password2 );
```

which is nestled in an on-click.  It works flawlessly, it adds the user to the table using the php file.  Now how am I supposed to let my activity know that the entry was successful?  Is there a way to read a response?

I tried searching but maybe I am looking for the wrong answers here, just a little confused.  Thank you for any help or direction.

Comment: you want responestring in activity?

Comment: a response string would be nice yes.  But really, any kind of unique response would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface as a callback to the activity.

Define a interface. Let your activity implement the interface. Use the interface as a cll back to the activity and return `responseString`.

Example :

[How do I return a boolean from AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask)

Comment: I would rather not return a boolean, I would like to read the response from the page

Comment: @user3053446 that was an example. It does not matter response or boolean value. it is data. same method no difference