# error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown (calling AsyncTask)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This is my class that extends AsyncTask

```
public class JSONFunctions extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        String line = "";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://appDev.milasevicius.com/server/homeresults.php");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            if(response != null) {
                InputStream inputstream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                line = convertStreamToString(inputstream);
            } else {
               line = "Unable to complete your request";
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            line = "Caught ClientProtocolException";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            line = "Caught IOException";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            line = "Caught Exception";
        }

        return line;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
}
```

And this is my call:

```
String output = new JSONFunctions().execute().get();
```

But compilator says that

```
error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

sorry for my noobish question, but how to fix that? And am I doing right call to get result?

Comment: do not call `get()`. remove it

Comment: get is a blocking call that can throw InterruptException. Usually you have to catch it, but in this case you should avoid to call get(), because it will block the UI Thread (or the thread where you are invoking it)

Comment: Can you write simple snippet how to get result then? Thankyou.

Comment: @Rokas here's answer from blackbelt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask

Comment: @Rokas did you try the suggestion?

Comment: Yes, still trying to figure it out, as im just started programming java/android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public final Result get ()

Added in API level 3
Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Returns
The computed result.
Throws
CancellationException   If the computation was cancelled.
ExecutionException  If the computation threw an exception.
InterruptedException    If the current thread was interrupted while waiting.
```

`get()` throws `InterrruptedException`. Your log says you need to catch those.

Also you should not call `get()` coz its blocks the ui thread waiting fro the result. You should not block the ui thread.

Remove `get()` and invoke as `new JSONFunctions().execute()`.

To get the result in the activity use a interface

Example @

[How do I return a boolean from AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask)

Answer (score 0):

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29)

A bare InterruptedException being thrown from .get() indicates that the current thread of execution 
            (the one calling .get()) was interrupted before calling get(), or while blocked in .get(). 
        This is not the same thing as an executor thread or one of its tasks being interrupted.
     Someone or 
             something is interrupting your "main" thread -- or at least the thread calling .get().

Use

```
new JSONFunctions().execute()
```

instead of

```
new JSONFunctions().execute().get();
```