# Whats the point of having an async task when get() waits for it to complete

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask

I am using below code to get result from Asynctask

```
Ui thread
.....
....
    int result = new MyCustomTask().execute().get();

    if (result == 1) {
    }
    else {
    }
----
----
```

But my doubt is "Whats the point of having an async task when get() waits for it to complete"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No point in calling `get()`.

Just have

```
new MyCustomTask().execute();
```

Calling `get()` blocks the ui thread waiting for the result. This makes AsyncTask no more Asynchronous.

The result of `doInbackground` computation is param to `onPostExecute`. So you can retrun result in `doInbackground` and update ui in `onPostExecute`.

You can use `onPostExecute()` to update ui if its a inner class of Activity or you can use interface as a callback to the activity to get the result.

Use interface as a callback

[How do I return a boolean from AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask)

Comment: Yes..for this write your condition in onPostExecute() so which will not block the UI thread.