# Android Login Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am new to Android.

I have a UI thread, the user clicks "Login." Once they click login, a thread is created (Android's AsyncTask) that goes to the internet (HTTPPost) and validates the input. There is also a "Progress Bar." Now my question is, how do I go back to the Activity (UI thread?) so I can close and start a new activity.

One naive idea that I came up with was to make the AsyncTask class a subclass of the Activity. This way in the "onPostExecute" method, I can finish the Activity.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass `context` of activity in the `contructor of asyntask` and in `onPostExecute` you can close that activity by its `context` and `startActivity` from there.

```
public class MyAsyn extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

public MyAsyn(Context con) {
    context = con;
}

}
```

and then in onPostExecute do

```
i = new Intent(context,AnotherActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                    ((Activity) context).finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

**call this method in async task**

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if(progressDialog!=null&&progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could make Asynctask an inner class of the Activity and use startActivity in `onPostExecute`.

If its in a spearate .java file then you can pass context to the constructor of asynctask and `startActivity`

Or you could use interface as a callback to the Activity and start Activity in activity itself. You could also use a Handler.

[How do I return a boolean from AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask)

Answer (score 1):

Call startActivity in the postexecute method of AsyncTask. This will return to the Activity class.