# Pass an Object From AsyncTask doInBackground to OnPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im trying to pass an object from doInBackground to OnPostExecute but failed.
I have read similar topics and find them not relevant. (Maybe im not that experienced enough)
I'm new to android would like some pointers.
I will paste relevant codes instead of everything for easier readability.

Main Activity

```
public void processFinish(Question q) {
    TextView tview;
    tview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tview.setText(q.getQuestion());
}
```

AsyncTask (Q is an object)

```
public class getQus extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Question> {
public AsyncResponse delegate;
@Override
protected Question doInBackground(String... params) {
    String range = "1";
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("range",range));
    int q_id = 0;
    String result=null;
    String q_qus =" ";
    String result2 = " ";

    Question q = new Question();

     InputStream is = null;
        try {

              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.6/fyp/qus.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();

                result2=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
         System.out.println("HEllo");
        //parse json data
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result2);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("q_id")+
                                ", qus: "+json_data.getString("q_qus")
                        );
                        q.setQid(json_data.getInt("q_id"));
                        q.setQuestion(json_data.getString("q_qus"));
                        return q;
                }

        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
        return q;

}
protected void onPostExecute(Question q) {
    System.out.println("AT ONPOSTEXECUTE");
    System.out.println(q.getQuestion());
    delegate.processFinish(q);
}
```

}

Findings:
I am able to see my log.i results in my console only.
OnPostExecute does not fire at all.

Any Kind Help Or Suggestions would be deeply appreciated.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Object>
```

to

```
 extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Question>
```

the third generic parameter is the Result. From the doc

> Result, the type of the result of the background computation.

For the NPE:

```
public class getQus extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Question> {
public AsyncResponse delegate;
   public getQus(AsyncResponse d) {
       delegate = d;
   }
   // other code
}
```

and if your activity is implementing that interface you simply do:

```
new getQus(ActivityName.this).execute();
```

Comment: can you post the whole AsyncTask?

Comment: Here you go ! @Blackbelt Thanks!

Comment: Im using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a answer for the passing of results from onpostexecute to main activity.

Comment: `delegate` is null. You never initialize it. Who is the delegate? Take a look to my answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask

Comment: What do you mean by that bro? I did initialise it on the top, changing to public AsyncResponse delegate = null; doesnt work either.

Comment: is AsyncResponse an interface?

Comment: Hi Yes! this is the following codes for the interface..
public interface AsyncResponse {
 void processFinish(Question q);
}

Comment: who is implementing that interface?

Comment: Then create a constructor in the async task, and pass the activity as parameter. Assign the parameter to the delegate

Comment: What do you mean by that? Im kinda confused right now.

Comment: Thanks for all your help blackbelt. I will try to solve and if really cant, will post an separate thread. Kinda unfair to you. Thank you very much!