# AsyncTask static, different type of parameters and returning value. Android.osNetworkthreadException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have to do a lot of different things that AsyncTask doesn't allow (or maybe I don't know how to do). I have a class that call AsyncTask method (AsyncTask is another class) and I need to pass a String and an Integer, my AsyncTask has to open an online file  and catch items and return a String[]. I was thinking to have solved my problem but it doesn't work with some android OS returning android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException so I don't know other way to solve and I don't know what is the problem. My code:

```
public class Methods extends Activity{
static String url = "http://www.MYADDRESS.com/";
static String ConfPath = new String();

static public String[] Read(String path, int LinesNumber) throws InterruptedException{
    try {
        return new AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String[]>(){
             @Override
             public String[] doInBackground(Object... params) {
                 try {
                     String[] menus = new String [(int) params[1]];
                     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url+params[0]).openStream()));
                     String line = reader.readLine();
                     for (int k = 0; k < (int) params[1]; k++) {
                         menus[k] = line;
                         line = reader.readLine();
                     }
                     return  menus;
                 }
                 catch (IOException e){
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

                 return null;
             }


         }.execute(path,LinesNumber).get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You are killing the purpose of Async Task. You should return or perhaps implement a callback method and call that in onPostExecute Method.

Comment: how I pass returning value to onPostExecute Method ?

Comment: override the onpostexecute method in asynctask an receive Strings[] as params and then you can do hat ever you want. Also it runs on UI thread.

Comment: You should create an interface and implement that interface in the class from which you are calling this function. Then pass the reference of that class (calling class) to this class (in which you have implemented asynctask) in parameters and call the method of the interface in onpostexecute. If you want to return string[] then your interface method should be of parameter with string[]. I hope you get what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is

```
.execute(path,LinesNumber).get();
```

that makes the UI Thread wait the execution of your AsyncTask, since get is a blocking call. You should use just `.execute(path,LinesNumber);`

Comment: removing .get() seems that my code return an AsyncTask type and not a String[]

Comment: yes it does. To get the results you can use the delegate pattern. For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask

Comment: Maybe I have solved in another way, I have a problem with doInBackground, How can I make it not returning?

Comment: `How can I make it not returning?`: just ignore the return value

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, I can't write protected void doInBackground and if protected String[] doInBackground it wants return

Comment: `AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String[]>`, the third paramter is the return value. You can use `Void`