# ProgressDialog appears too late and disappears too fast

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog, slidingmenu

I try to show a progress dialog upon showing a sliding drawer.

this is opening drawer event handler:

```
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) { 
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "dialog title",
            "dialog message", true);

    openDrawer();
}
```

Inside `openDrawer()` i call a function `fillCommunityList()` that i need to show the progress dialog while its execution

`fillCommunityList()` implementation is as the following:

```
private void fillCommunityList(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                // Here you should write your time consuming task...
                UIManager manager = new UIManager(activity);
                coms = manager.getCommunities();
                progress.dismiss();
                getOutTread = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            getOutTread = false;
        }
    }).start();
    // to stop code till thread be finished
    while(getOutTread){ }

    SlidingMenuExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SlidingMenuExpandableListAdapter(this,
            navDrawerItems, coms, mDrawerList);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Note:
I put a thread just to make progress dialog works

My problem is the following two points:

1- progress dialog appears too late for sudden and then disappears

2- Thread takes alot of time in its execution (without thread `fillCommunityList()` takes around 10 seconds but with a thread it takes more than a minute)

Note: `manager.getCommunities()` has asyncTask in its implementation

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the following line

```
 while(getOutTread){ }
```

this is call [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). The UI Thread is busy looping and can't, at the same time, draw/update the `ProgressDialog`

Comment: thank you for reply. "fillCommunityList()" get some data, i use this data for population the sliding menu. so i need to stop performing the remaining code till finishing code in the thread. Ho to do that without using while(getOutTread){ } ?

Comment: One solution is to use the delegate pattern. Like a listenrt. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask . it   is about async task but the same concept can be easily applied also to your situation

Comment: more description please !

Comment: did you see the link?