# My cursor becomes null when I use async task?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-asynctask, database-cursor

I have a database code that takes data from my table & stores it into my cursor but running the database code on the main thread slows down my app when I open the activity that displays the data on a recycler view. So I moved the database code to an asyntask inner class & tried running it.

However, after asyntask runs in the `onCreate ()` my recycler view adapter code runs & the `getItemCount ()` called on the cursor object throws a `null pointer exception` because the cursor is null.

From debugging I have found where the cursor becomes null but don't understand why it becomes null. the cursor when the `accessDatabase ()` runs is not null but after the asynctask inner class runs in the `onCreate ()` the cursor becomes null.

**Code in the onCreate method:**

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.item_grocery);

    RecyclerView groceryRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.grocery_recycler_view);

    StartDatabase sd = new StartDatabase();
    sd.execute(databaseHelper);
    Log.d ("blue", "sd has ran");

    if (cursor == null) {
        Log.d ("green", "cursor is null");//I receive this in the log cat
    }

    captionedImagesAdapter adapter = new captionedImagesAdapter (this, cursor);
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    groceryRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    groceryRecycler.setAdapter (adapter);
}
```

***The async task inner class:***

```
private class StartDatabase extends AsyncTask<MyDatabaseHelper, Void, Boolean> {

    protected void onPreExecute () {}

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(MyDatabaseHelper... myDatabaseHelpers) {
        try {
            accessDataBase();

            return true;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            return false;

        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute (Boolean success) {
        if (!success) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(grocery_item.this, "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

        }
    }
}
```

***The access database method:***

```
public void accessDataBase () {

    try {

        db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = db.query ("GROCERY_DATA", new String[] {"NAME", "PATHS"}, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            Log.d ("blue", "cursor is null");
        }

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

***My recycle view adapter:***

```
public class captionedImagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <captionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private Cursor cursor;

public captionedImagesAdapter (Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cursor = cursor;

    if (this.cursor == null) {
        Log.d ("red", "cursor is null");//I receive this in the log cat 
    }
}

public captionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    CardView cv = (CardView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder (cv);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (!cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        return;
    }

    String info_text = cursor.getString (0);
    holder.textView.setText(info_text);


    String image_Path = cursor.getString(1);
    File file = new File (image_Path);

    if (file.exists()) {

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile (file.getAbsolutePath());

        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}

public int getItemCount() {
    return cursor.getCount();//Line throwing the exception
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(CardView view) {
        super(view);
        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.info_image);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
    }
}
```

}

***The exception I am receiving:***

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getCount()' on a null object reference
    at com.myapps.myapplication.captionedImagesAdapter.getItemCount(captionedImagesAdapter.java:58)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4135)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3939)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:786)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3333)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2810)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1930)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7988)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1154)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:977)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:893)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler.handleMessage(Choreographer.java:1082)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: Set your adapter in postexecute() of your async task and you should be good to go

Comment: Main thread will not wait untill  to complete AsyncTask. I think this is problem getting null. You can put whole adapter class in onPostExecute().

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons you are getting it null is due to the wrong assumption that the Main thread is waiting for the async task to complete. That is, of course, wrong (otherwise you won't be needing a different thread). You have different options to fix it, for example:

- <s>Use the [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/CursorLoader.html)</s>  (deprecated)
- Use a callback to notify the UI Thread, when the <s>AsyncTask</s> (deprecated) is done loading the cursor. An example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask)
- Look into a different technology, like [coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines)

Comment: - Consider any other async solution (Rx, ThreadPool, Coroutines, ...). AsyncTask and Loaders are outdated afaik.

Comment: fair point on the asynctask. Not for the loaders imo

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders
"Loaders have been deprecated as of Android P (API 28)."

Comment: I missed that. Thanks @Kikiwa